# How to show different data to different users in flask application?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

I have created a flask application and using mysql as DB backend and this is used by multiple users simultaneously.

The problem I'm having is,In my homepage a select query is performed and data is displayed to the user but same data is showing to all users.it should be unique. I have tried to lock the row by using  **FOR UPDATE** while selecting the row. I know that I'm not updating the row,so the transaction will be closed when the function ends and the row will be released from lock.

How to overcome this problem?

Expected output: Each user should get different data from the table.(Even when they refresh)

```
@is_logged_in
@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = mysql.connection
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("select mylist ,myurl ,swatch,parent from image_links where status =%s LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE",("fetched",))
    parent = cur.fetchall()
    for row in parent:
        mylistitems = row[0].split(",")
        swatches = row[2].split(",")
        myurlsitems = row[1].split(",")
        pid = row[3]
    if asinlist != ['']:
        merged = tuple(zip(mylistitems ,myurlsitems ,swatches))
        return render_template('home.html',firstimage= myurlsitems[0],merged=merged)
    else:
        cur.execute("UPDATE asin_links SET status = %s WHERE pid= %s", ("invalid",pid,))
        conn.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any "current user" specific parameters used in your sql query or any data filtering decided on some user ID.
Basically, if you are running the same code, same query for all requests on this endpoint, it will never be really unique. You need to add some user specific checks so you can differentiate the output for the current requesting user.

Depending on your use-case and database models, if the data in the table `image_links` is also created/inserted by some user action you might want additionally save some user ID alongside these values, eg. by extending the table model with another "user_id" column and on insert also add the id of the current user.

You are using some auth decorator `@is_logged_in`, if you are already handling users in some table then the another `user_id` column could be a reference to the respective user's primary key. Then, in your example, you would just add additional `where user_id =` check with the current user's primary key.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT mylist, myurl, swatch, parent FROM image_links WHERE status
```

perhaps you did specify the related user to get its own specific data, try to replace that last "where" with:

```sql
WHERE id = (user.id) --> user object
```

or you could use the `AND` keyword, something like

```sql
WHERE status = (x) AND id = (y)
```